# Change domain when authenticating with IE8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, authentication, dns

When I try to login to our WSS demo site the authentication popup forces me to use the domain I'm currently using on my local computer. The WSS site does not have the same domain.

I'm running IE8 on Windows 7. How do I change the domain!?

Comment: If you're talking about changing the default domain name in browser dialog box, I don't think you can.

Comment: No I mean, the WSS site I'm trying to log on to does not have the same domain as my local computer. Editing the question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of my collegues helped me and now I feel like an idiot!

In IE8 the authentication popup first wants you to login as your domain user but you also have the choice to "Use another account". When clicking that choice your local domain is displayed below the texbox like "Domain: LOCALDOMAIN". And when you start typing "MYDOMAIN\xyz" in the username box it changes to "Domain: MYDOMAIN"!

Simple as that!

You will have to type the domain name in ALL CAPITALS, otherwise it does not take it

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer in case others stumble upon the same search with the same problem.

If you have an Azure VM and you did not establish a domain for the VM but the Windows Security popup is defaulting to your Windows Authentication credentials. You can omit the domain by using

"...\[yourLoginName]"

where [yourLoginName] is the VM username that you initially setup in Azure.